# How to use Unevaluated in postfix version?

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation

In the following versions,

```
Thread[Unevaluated@((1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)), Plus]    
Unevaluated[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)]~Thread~Plus
```

I get an expected result 32.

For learning purposes, I want to convert it to postfix version. Here is my attempt

```
Unevaluated[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)] // Thread[#, Plus] &
```

that produces an unexpected result of 90.

## Question

Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Use `Thread[Unevaluated @ #, Plus] &`

Comment: On Mathematica 13.0.1, I get `32`. `Unevaluated[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)] // Thread[Unevaluated@#, Plus] &`

Comment: @BenIzd: OK. It works.

Comment: I don't think this is a well-formed question. In your attempt at postfix, you had to introduce Function to turn the 2-argument form of Thread into a 1-argument function. This is not a simple translation from infix form to postfix form. Infix form requires you to have two arguments, while prefix and postfix requires you to have one argument. Are you actually trying to ask why the results were different?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to ask why the results were different. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question, "why different results?", we need to understand carefully how Unevaluated works. It's not like Hold. It's a little difficult to understand the documentation, but here's the important bit:

> Unevaluated works only where it appears; it is not propagated

So, the first example,

```
Unevaluated[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)]~Thread~Plus
```

is equivalant to

```
Thread[Unevaluated[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)], Plus]
```

The Unevaluated bit is "held" and so Thread works on that unevaluated form, which eventually gives `1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6`.

In the attempted postfix example,

```
Unevaluated[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)] // Thread[#, Plus] &
```

which is equivalent to

```
Thread[#1, Plus] &[Unevaluated[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6)]]
```

we encounter an extra step to get us to:

```
Thread[(1 + 2 + 3) (4 + 5 + 6), Plus]
```

The extra step was doing the slot replacements into the Function. Since the Unevaluated is not propagated, we now have just the raw product expression as the first argument in the resulting Thread. That product gets evaluated at this point to give us

```
Thread[90, Plus]
```

which just resolves to 90.